# Remove the top margin of header in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="page-header header_site">
      <h1><font>ABC Company</font></h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS Code:

```
.header_site {
  background-color: darkblue;
}

font {
  color: white;
  margin: auto 160px auto 160px;
}
```

I want to remove the top-margin as marked in the following figure.

[image]

Comment: `<font>` has been deprecated and should no longer be used. I'm surprised they're still teaching that.

Comment: You need do set `margin:0;`to `h1`and on the class `.page-header` to `margin-top:0`

Comment: @Paulie_D Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

give your h1 and page header a margin-top of 0 and make sure your body doesn't have any padding:

```
body { padding: 0; }
.page-header,
.page-header h1 {margin-top:0;}
```

[Example bootply](http://www.bootply.com/y41sR5NB5R)

If you need your `h1` to move down a bit, then give it `padding-top`

Answer (score 12):

For Bootstrap 3 just add class "media-heading"

```
<h1 class="media-heading"><font>ABC Company</font></h1>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
h3 {
  margin-top: revert !important;
  margin-bottom: revert !important;
}
```

It revert h3 style to browser style.  [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/revert#:%7E:text=The%20revert%20CSS%20keyword%20reverts,origin%20to%20the%20current%20element.) said it does not work on chrome but I checked and it works well.

Answer (score 1):

Modify the style as below

```
.header_site {
  background-color: darkblue;
  margin:0;
  float:left;
  width:100%
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add the below **css**.In default **HTML** have it's own `margin` for `h1` tag that's why its happening add `margin-top:0;` in `.page-header h1` class.

```
.page-header h1 { margin-top: 0; }
```

```css
.header_site {
  background-color: darkblue;
}
font {
  color: white;
  margin: auto 160px auto 160px;
}
.page-header h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="page-header header_site">
      <h1><font>ABC Company</font></h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just rewrite class `page-header` and tag `<h1>`:

```
.page-header {
  margin: 0 0 20px;
}
.page-header h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

[jsfiddle-link](https://jsfiddle.net/Igor_Ivancha/f8wkynvh/1/)